# How to check if UWP app was just updated?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a WPF app exported via MSIX as a UWP app.

I want to show a changelog window once when the app gets updated. How do I do that?

Comment: Add a configuration setting like "FirstStartAfterUpdate". Only reset it during a update.

Comment: Yeah it seems that's the way. I was expecting that UWP would have a more elegant solution to check for that, but apparently not. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to check if UWP app was just updated?

I think you could store current app's version to `LoclSetting`, when you launch the app and compare current version with [LocalSetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data) value, if they are different, you could show a dialog and told user app has updated, then replace `LocalSetting`  with current version.

```
public static string GetAppVersion()
{
    Package package = Package.Current;
    PackageId packageId = package.Id;
    PackageVersion version = packageId.Version;

    return string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", version.Major, version.Minor, version.Build, version.Revision);
}
```

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer as the logic is basically the same.